# In CPLEX C# version, can I deactivate output when main runs?

Tags: cplex

I use C# and I call CPLEX main function. Code:

```
if (opl.ModelDefinition.hasMain())
{                            
     status = opl.Main();
}
```

When program runs, I get output about running model. Example:

```
 ! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ! Satisfiability problem - 21 variables, 221 constraints
 ! Presolve      : 5 extractables eliminated, 1 constraint generated
 ! Workers              = 1
 ! Initial process time : 0.06s (0.02s extraction + 0.03s propagation)
 !  . Log search space  : 112.9 (before), 112.9 (after)
 !  . Memory usage      : 1.7 MB (before), 1.7 MB (after)
 ! Using sequential search.
 ! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 !               Branches  Non-fixed            Branch decision
 *                      4 0.11s                 132  = _int12
 *                      6 0.12s                  21  = _int9
 *                      7 0.13s                  22  = _int9
 *                     11 0.13s                  38  = _int13
 *                     15 0.14s                 132  = _int10
 *                     16 0.15s                 133  = _int10
 *                     17 0.16s                  22  = _int9
 *                     20 0.16s                 132  = _int10
 *                     22 0.17s                 133  = _int10
```

...
...

This makes program slow because of the output. Can I deactivate writing output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to disable the output is to change the "Log Verbosity" and "Log Period" parameters of the CP engine. This can be done either in the `.mod` file or by supplying an `.ops` file with the appropriate settings.

**UPDATE:** In order to set things in the `.mod` file, put this line into the file

```
execute { cp.param.LogVerbosity = "quiet"; }
```

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution by looking Python code sample and trying adopting to c#. Same function names are similar :)